# Why are Kobato's eyes inconsistent in color between episodes?

Tags: boku-wa-tomodachi-ga-sukunai

In Boku wa Tomodachi ga Sukunai, Kobato (Kodaka's sister) appears to have [Heterochromia iridum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heterochromia_iridum).

Her right eye is red and her left eye is blue.

[image]

But in episode 5 of the first season, both her eyes are blue.

[image]

### What gives?

Is she wearing contacts? I wasn't able to find an explanation for this from the Anime.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is not heterochromia. The manga does explain it better and ...

- her normal eye color is blue.
- she is wearing a contact lens.

There is also a mention of her mother being English and having red eye color. So wearing a contact might be a fashion statement.

Answer (score 5):

Her eye is not those kind of special eye or Heterochromia type , she is wearing eye contact to match with the anime character she's cosplaying

Comment: Is it a specific anime character or is she just trying to look cool/different/unique?